# Multiple Interpreters vs multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to understand why multiple interpreters should be an advantage against multiprocessing.

Multiple interpreters may be introduced in Python 3.9 according to [PEP 554](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0554/#concerns) (currently draft).

For me, it seems that both multiprocessing and multiple interpreters have as the main purpose to take advantage of multiple CPU cores.

With what should be multiple interpreters better? Or for which cases?

Comment: Subinterpreters are not designed to take advantage of multiple CPU cores. Additional work would be needed to use them as a parallelism tool. Also, PEP 554 is a draft, not accepted.

Comment: right, may be introduced in python3.9 since is just a draft currently

Comment: @user2357112 how come, multiple interpreters, are not designed to take advantage of multiple cores? from Eric Snow (the author of PEP 554) blog (http://ericsnowcurrently.blogspot.com/2016/09/solving-mutli-core-python.html) and his repo(https://github.com/ericsnowcurrently/multi-core-python) it seems  that the main purpose is to take advantage of multiple CPU/ multi-core, he is saying multi-core parallelism, but still it is multi-core advantage

Comment: Subinterpreters have been around for quite a while as an obscure C-API-only feature. Throughout that time, they have still been bound by the GIL. Eric wants to extend them to support parallel execution, but that is not something they currently provide.

Comment: you are right, currently is not something they currently provide

Comment: @-ing people doesn't work like that here. You can't ping someone on a post if they haven't interacted with that post yet.

Comment: thanks, I deleted the "ping"